# Some JavaScript Grammar Questions on React-Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have read source code on https://github.com/stage88/react-weather
I find there are some strange JS grammars in it, for example:

```
type Props = {
    postcodes: Array<Postcode>;
    dispatch: any;
    navigator: any;
};
```

and

```
(this: any).onSearchBarPressed = this.onSearchBarPressed.bind(this);
```

I can not find detail description for this by Google and Mozilla Developer Network, does React-Native make them? Webstrom also show errors for these code :(

Is there any detail explanation for these grammar ?

Comment: This is definitively is not JS.

Comment: By the way webstorm has support for flow by default. You can find it in setting of language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This project is using [Flow](https://flowtype.org/), a static type checker (which looks deceptively like TypeScript).

Comment: Flow *is* JavaScript! Just with type annotations on top of it. You can even put them within comments and be 100% valid JavaScript.